# How Can I get the coordinates of the vertices of all the GameObjects with an specific Tag and save them in a Json file?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, unity-game-engine, mesh

I hope you are fine :)

I could get the vertices of one the elementes with the specific tag in my scene, nevertheless when I try to do it with a list of GameObjects (all the gameObjects with the tag "wallTag") it doesn't work.

Also I tryied to store the vertices into a json file but it doesn't work neither.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Have a great day!

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public void Start()
     {
 
  walls = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("wallTag");
 
         Transform wallTransform = walls.transform;
 
         Mesh wallMesh = walls.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
 
         Vector3[] vertices = wallMesh.vertices;
 
         var text = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
 
         int numVertices = vertices.Length;
 
         for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
         {
             Vector3 vertexWorldPosition = wallTransform.TransformPoint(vertices[i]);
             text.AppendLine($", ({vertexWorldPosition.x:0.00},{vertexWorldPosition.y:0.00},{vertexWorldPosition.z:0.00})");
         }
 
         Debug.Log($"vertices: ({text})");
     }
```

I only could had the vertices of one of the GameObjects in a Log on the screen but I need to store all the vertices of all the GameObjects with the specified tag into a JSON file

Comment: Hi JuanSB, any chance this occurs because you are calling `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag()` as opposed to `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag()` (plural)

Comment: Store the resulting vertices in a structure and serialize that structure to json.  Unity provides [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) for json serialization, or you can use a 3rd party solution.